# Of what type is the SwiftUI "body" variable?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Quick question: what exactly is the body variable? If I am correct in my interpretation of Swift, it is initialized as an object of View or one of its subclasses. However, inside its initialization, there seem to be a series of constructor calls (such as Text() or Image()) that are not stored in any variable or returned. I am new to Swift coming from Java and I was not able to find much about this online. Could someone please explain?

Also, same for VStack and HStack--are they collections of objects?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello SwiftUI!")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Preview: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: the return could be avoided, if there is only one expression, which is true in your example. computed property body has a type VStack<Text> in this case. 'some View' means some concrete type which adopts View protocol.

Answer (score 3):

it is easy to check. try the next in your Playground

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello SwiftUI!")
        }
    }
}

let cv = ContentView()
print("type of ContentView.body:", type(of: cv.body))
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(cv)
```

it prints

```
type of ContentView.body: VStack<Text>
```

**Even though View is a protocol, the struct adopting it MUST HAVE A CONCRETE TYPE.**

it could be written as

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        let t = Text("Hello World!")
        let content: ()-> Text = {
            return t
        }
        let vs = VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0, content: content)
        return vs
    }
}

let cv = ContentView()
print("type of ContentView.body:", type(of: cv.body))
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(cv)
```

with the same result .-)

**DON'T TRY TO DEFINE A CLASS CONFORMING TO VIEW PROTOCOL!**

this code will compile without error, but it will crash ... Yes, there is a lot to improve, I expect that the compilation will fail.

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

final class ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        let t = Text("Hello World!")
        let content: ()-> Text = {
            return t
        }
        let vs = VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0, content: content)
        return vs
    }
}

let cv = ContentView()
print("type of ContentView.body:", type(of: cv.body))
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(cv)
```

Answer (score 2):

`View` is a protocol, not a class. The type of `body` is `some View`, which is an opaque result type, meaning it returns some particular concrete type that implements `View`, but that concrete type isn't exposed to the public as part of the API.

SwiftUI uses Swift's the function builder syntax, though I'm not sure how you could ever figure that out yourself without first reading it from somewhere else.

Further reading: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/the-swift-51-features-that-power-swiftuis-api/

Comment: hm ... see my answer.

Comment: What about it? The type of the value returned by this particular implementation of `body` is `VStack<Text>`, but the type of `body` is still `some View`. Just like how `func f() -> Any { return 123 }` has a return type of `Any`. The concrete type happens to be `Int`, but that's an implementation detail that's not exposed in the interface (which is the whole point of opaque return types)

Comment: opaque types let you use protocols with associated types as return types, which was impossible before.

Comment: "What about it?" my hm... was about "SwiftUI uses Swift's the function builder syntax", which is not general rules to construct the body of View.

Comment: and finaly func getSomeAny()-> some Any { return 123 } is also valid now. That is because Any is protocol to which all Swift types conforms (value or reference)

Comment: "opaque types let you use protocols with associated types as return types, which was impossible before. " yep. "my hm... was about "SwiftUI uses Swift's the function builder syntax", which is not general rules to construct the body of View. " I don't understand what you're pointing out in this sentence. "and finaly func getSomeAny()-> some Any { return 123 } is also valid now. That is because Any is protocol to which all Swift types conforms (value or reference)" Int could *always* be returned where `Any` was expected, but that wasn't my point.

Comment: do you see any function builder in my answer? OP was confused by the declarative syntax, he didn't see what is returned from the body computed variable ... he didn't know, that return could be avoided there and why ... That is clear for you, but not clear for somebody who see some SwiftUI code first time, even though he try to find some documentation provided by Apple.

Comment: "That is clear for you, but not clear for somebody who see some SwiftUI code first time, even though he try to find some documentation provided by Apple." Yep, there's no particualr keyword or anything to signal that something is going on here. I said this in my answer: "SwiftUI uses Swift's the function builder syntax, though I'm not sure how you could ever figure that out yourself without first reading it from somewhere else."